# Segmentation fault for radix sort C

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to run radix sort by splitting digits into 8 but numbers and sorting it. This is the code I have written so far. I am getting stuck with segmentation fault and I'm not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
// #include <omp.h>

#include "sort.h"
#include "edgelist.h"


void radixSortEdgesBySource(struct Edge *edges_sorted, struct Edge *edges, int numVertices, int numEdges) {


    int i,j;
    int *vertex_cnt = (int *) malloc (256 * sizeof(int)); 

    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)  //Radix Sort for d digits
    {
    //int *vertex_cnt = (int *) malloc ((1<<8) * sizeof(int));

        for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) 
        {
            vertex_cnt[i] = 0;
        }     

        for(i = 0; i < numEdges; ++i) 
        {       
            vertex_cnt[(edges[i].src >> 8*j) & ((1 << 8) - 1)]++;
        }


        for(i = 1; i < 257; ++i)
        {
            vertex_cnt[i] += vertex_cnt[i - 1];    
        }

        for(i = numEdges - 1; i >= 0; --i) {  
        //printf("KEY: %d\n", (edges[i].src >> 8*j) & ((1 << 8) - 1));      
            edges_sorted[--vertex_cnt[(edges[i].src >> 8*j) & ((1 << 8) - 1)]] = edges[i];
        }
        edges = edges_sorted;        
    //free(vertex_cnt);
    }
   // free(vertex_cnt);

 }
```

The values `edges` and `edges_sorted` are defined as:

```
  struct Edge{
    int src;      // id of a source vertex
    int dest;     // id of a destination vertex
};

struct Edge * newEdgeArray(int numOfEdges);
```

Could someone help me out with why I get segmentation error?

Comment: Any time you have an expression as complicated as `(edges[i].src >> 8*j) & ((1 << 8) - 1)` and you're _using it as an array index_.... step back, assign the value to a variable, and check that it's within the array bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory for 256 elements:

```
int *vertex_cnt = (int *) malloc (256 * sizeof(int));
```

but then iterate the array as if it had 257 elements:

```
    for(i = 1; i < 257; ++i)
```

I highly recommend learning to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). You'll be able to catch the exact line where the memory access error happens.

Comment: for(i = 0; i < 256; ++i) is probably what you want